# Use Hangfire job id in the code

Tags: c#, jobs, hangfire

I'm doing a Fire-and-Forget method invocation like this.

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => SendEmail(name));
```

I would like to pass the job id to the SendEmail() method and use it inside the method.

Comment: `BackgroundJob.Enqueue((string id) => SendEmail(name, id));`. In case this method accepts an id parameter.

Comment: @meJustAndrew I tried your code snippet. But it doesn't invoke the method.

Comment: does it generate an error?

Comment: @meJustAndrew No it doesn't create a new background job.

Comment: can you tell me please from where is the `SendEmail` method/ what signature does it have?

Comment: @meJustAndrew Method is inside the same class and the method signature is 'string SendEmail(string name)'

Comment: @AkiT If you want to pass Job id to SendEmail method then you need to change the SendEmail method to signature to accept  `id` along with the `name`.  Then it should work automatically.

Comment: @meJustAndrew Actually I'm getting an Exception, '{"variable 'id' of type 'System.String' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined"}'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easy way is to  add

> PerformContext

to the job method:. Hangfire Forum topic [Use Hangfire job id in the code](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/use-hangfire-job-id-in-the-code/2621/3).

Comment: Please add the solution instead of referencing it. It'll be useful in case the link goes down.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `SendEmail` method to look like this...

```
public void SendEmail(string name, string jobId)
{ 
//Body of method
}
```

Change the Hangfire call to look like this...

```
BackgroundJob.Enqueue((string jobId) => SendEmail(name, jobId));
```

Unless, you're looking to run a job, and send an email one complete, then you might have to do the following...

```
  var jobId = BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => TaskToRun);
  BackgroundJob.ContinueWith(jobId, () => SendEmail(name, jobId));
```

Comment: any one get this error "variable 'jobId' of type 'System.String' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined" when use the second methd